# Is a GenServer :continue call synchronous?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

A `GenServer` `handle_call/3` implementation can return `:continue` to invoke an additional function.  Are there any guarantees as to when this function will run relative to other messages?

For example, consider this module that just keeps a running counter:

```elixir
defmodule Tmp do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(opts), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, 0, opts)
  def incr(tmp), do: GenServer.call(tmp, :incr)

  @impl true
  def init(state), do: {:ok, state}

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:incr, _from, n) do
    {:reply, n, n, {:continue, :incr}}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_continue(:incr, n) do
    {:noreply, n+1}
  end
end
```

When you call `Tmp.incr/1`, the `handle_call/3` method returns the current value of the counter, but then also returns `:continue`.  This causes the `GenServer` infrastructure to call `handle_continue/2`.

If I call `Tmp.incr/1` twice in succession, am I *guaranteed* to get incrementing values?  Or is it possible that `handle_call/3` will be called twice before `handle_continue/2` is called at all?

```
iex> {:ok, tmp} = Tmp.start_link([])
iex> Tmp.incr(tmp)
0
iex> Tmp.incr(tmp)
1
# If I type fast enough, will this ever return 0?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `:continue` is synchronous - the continue will be executed immediately after the function you returned it from. Its use-case is exactly that: guaranteeing it will be run right after, which could not be guaranteed by other methods such as `:timeout` or sending a message to yourself with `send(self(), :incr)`.

This is briefly mentioned in [the documentation for GenServer callbacks](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/GenServer.html#c:handle_call/3):

> Returning {:reply, reply, new_state, {:continue, continue}} is similar to {:reply, reply, new_state} except handle_continue/2 will be invoked immediately after with the value continue as first argument.

Also on [the Timeout section](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/GenServer.html#module-timeouts):

> Because a message may arrive before the timeout is set, even a timeout of 0 milliseconds is not guaranteed to execute. To take another action immediately and unconditionally, use a :continue instruction.

Comment: Aha, highlighting the asynchronous alternatives is helpful.  Thanks!